# Embedding php script into an href that is already embedded into a php script

Tags: php, html

I have the following code, and this is the entire page. I am frustrated because I cannot find a complete example while researching on the web, but only spinets that are not really answering my question.

The section of this code that is troubling is this line as show below:

```
echo "<p><a style=\"font-size:40px; font-family:segoe script bold; color:green\" href="<?php echo $web_path; ?>">Mail Server</a></p>";
```

and more specifically  this part of it:

```
href="<?php echo $web_path; ?>"
```

The entire PHP page is shown below:

```
<?php
        include 'debug.php'; 
        //  Remember for later.
        // header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        session_start();

        $username = $_SESSION["fusername"];
        $password = $_SESSION["fpassword"];
        $web_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/UserPages/mail_login.html";


        if ($username === "name_of_user") 
        {

            echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang=\"en-US\">
                <head><title> The title text goes here </title></head>
                <!-- Comments -->
                <body>
                <h6><center> Company name text goes here  </center><br><h6>";

            echo "<center><p style=\"font-size:80px; font-family:segoe script bold\"><span style=\"color:blue\"> First Name</span><span style=\"color:red\"> Last Name</span></p></center>";
            echo "<p><a style=\"font-size:40px; font-family:segoe script bold; color:green\" href=\"get_dir_lists.php\">Directory Listing</a></p>";
            echo "<p><a style=\"font-size:40px; font-family:segoe script bold; color:green\" href="<?php echo $web_path; ?>">Mail Server</a></p>";
            echo "<center><p ><a style=\"font-size:40px; font-family:segoe script bold; color:yellow\" href=\"/login.html\">Return to Login Screen</a></p></center>";

            echo "</body></html>";
        }
          else
            {
                echo "Ain't workin";
            }              
?>
```

My question is: How to embed PHP script into an href that is already embedded into a PHP script (or page)?

I know I am close but the way I have the quotes or are missing the concatenating dots is just not right. The closing ?> at the end of the page is not being recognized as a PHP closing statement.

For other readers who need to see a more simplified example I have cut out all of the unnecessary code below so that the entire PHP page is simplified to a few lines for better viewing and clarity:

```
<?php
    echo "<p><a href="<?php echo $web_path; ?>">Mail Server</a></p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because you're already inside PHP and using a second `echo` plus you're not escaping the other double quotes.

```
echo "<p><a href="<?php echo $web_path; ?>">Mail Server</a></p>";
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^          ^ ^^^
```

Change it to

```
echo "<p><a href=\"$web_path\">Mail Server</a></p>";
```

or more specifically:

```
echo "<p><a style=\"font-size:40px; font-family:segoe script bold; color:green\" href=\"$web_path\">Mail Server</a></p>";
```

Having [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on, would have thrown:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'...

Something you either are not using, or haven't shared the (parse) error.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Alternate methods:

```
echo '<p><a href="'.$web_path.'">Mail Server</a></p>';
```

or

```
echo "<p><a href='$web_path'>Mail Server</a></p>";
```

Comment: This method:   echo "<p><a href=\"$web_path\">Mail Server</a></p>"; is working the best.

Answer (score 0):

Yout don't have to use `php` tags twice! And then also you don't have to echo the variable

So this should work:

```
<?php
    echo "<p><a href="$web_path">Mail Server</a></p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution is to use EOF syntax.

```
        echo <<<EOF
        <p><a href="<?php echo $web_path; ?>">Mail Server</a></p>
EOF;
```

It's also a good idea to use short-tags for echo statement in HTML

```
    echo <<<EOF
        <p><a href="<?= $web_path; ?>">Mail Server</a></p>
EOF;
```

This method is not a good idea in my opinion, you should probably do like the previous answer said.